# Gradle ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I have created an `Android Library` and have made it a dependency in my `Android Application`.

**Root `Gradle`**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "/Users/my.name/.m2/repository/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App `Gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.application.id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'SDK:library:unspecified'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
}
```

**The Problem**

When I run the application, I get the following error:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.some.library.view.InteractableWebView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/android.some.id.com.demo-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/android.some.id.com.demo-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]`

In Android Studio, when I click on the `Project View` and expand `External Libraries`, I can see the library which I have made and all it's classes. So it is being pulled in but it obviously isn't working at runtime.

It can compile, but it crashes at runtime. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your proguard obfuscating the class at runtime?

Comment: I just commented-out of the `pro guard` statements from both the `library` and the `app`. I then performed `clean, install and uploadArchives` tasks on the `library` but the issue still persists.

Comment: where is your library referenced in gradle, is it the 'SDK:library:unspecified' line?  It seems strange that you don't have a version number there, but not sure if that is the issue.

Comment: @dweebo Yes that's the one. The library is actually referencing another library too as that has dependencies of it's own. I don't think the version number is an issue because the library *does* seem to appear in my external libraries tab with all the objects there. So despite all the objects being shown in the external libraries tab, at runtime it crashes with the mentioned exception.

Comment: Hard to say without access to whole project but maybe hunt it down by running `gradlew app:dependencies` to see what libraries are being included (probably the same thing you are doing within Android Studio but worth a shot) and make sure you are getting the jar that has 'com.some.library.view.InteractableWebView'